# Is there a keyboard shortcut to circularly switch sheets in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2003

In this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/86941/keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-between-sheets-in-excel), he was asking about keyboard shortcut to switch tabs. But this shortcut moves the sheet backward or forward, which means that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> on the last sheet doesn't move the first sheet.

Is there any shortcut which allows circular switching (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> in Windows)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a simple version of what I described in the comment.

```
Sub SwitchSheets()
    Dim NextSheet As Worksheet
    Set NextSheet = ActiveSheet.Next
    If NextSheet Is Nothing Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
    Else
        NextSheet.Select
    End If
End Sub
```

From the `View` tab click on `Macros`, select `SwitchSheets`, go to `Options` and set a shortcut key for it (holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as needed, to add that into the chord).